# Angular ui-grid scrollTo on page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm using AngularJS ui-grid. I want to automatically scroll to a specific row when page is loading (when user returns to the page) but it does not work.

```js
$scope.notifType = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
   
 $scope.gridOptions = {
   rowHeight: 50,
   infiniteScrollPercentage : 15,
   enableSorting: false,

   columnDefs: [
    { 
     field: 'type', width: 50, displayName: '', 
     cellTemplate: '<div align="center" style="padding-top:10px">'
       +'<button class="btn btn-xs "'
       +' ng-click="getExternalScopes().displayChoosenNotifType(row.entity.type)" ' 
       +'tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{\'notification.tooltipFilter\' |translate}}<i>{{\'notification.type.type\'+row.entity.type | translate}}</i>"'
       +' ng-class="{'
       +'\'btn-primary\': row.entity.type==1,'
          +'\'btn-warning\': row.entity.type==2 ,'
          +'\'btn-danger\': row.entity.type==3||row.entity.type==4||row.entity.type==5,'
          +'\'btn-success\': row.entity.type==6,'
          +'\'btn-purple\': row.entity.type==7,'
       +'}">' 
       +'<span class="icon " '
       +' ng-class="{'
       +'\'icon-alarm\': row.entity.type==1,'
          +'\'icon-bell\': row.entity.type==2 ,'
          +'\'icon-warning\': row.entity.type==3||row.entity.type==4 ,'
          +'\'icon-pencil\': row.entity.type==5 ,'
          +'}">'       
          + '<span class="icon classicNotifIcon" ng-if="row.entity.type===6">C</span>'
          + '<span class="icon classicNotifIcon" ng-if="row.entity.type===7">M</span>'
       +'</span></button></div>',
       enableColumnMenu:true,enableHiding:false,
       menuItems:[
                  {
                   title: $translate.instant('notification.type.all'),
                   action: function(){
                    var notifType = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
                    $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
                   }
                  },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type1'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [1];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type2'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [2];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type3'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [3,4];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type5'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [5];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type6'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [6];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             },
             {
              title: $translate.instant('notification.type.type7'),
              action: function(){
               var notifType = [7];
               $scope.displayChoosenNotifType(notifType);
              }
             }
        ]
      },
   { field:'notification',
     cellTemplate: '<div style="padding-left:5px">'
      +'<a ng-click="getExternalScopes().modify(row.entity)" '
      +'ng-class="{'
      +'\'button\': row.entity.type==1 || row.entity.type==2 || row.entity.type==3 || row.entity.type==4 || row.entity.type==6 || row.entity.type==7,'
      +'\'classicNotif\': row.entity.type==5'
      +'}" '
      +'ng-attr-tooltip="{{row.entity.type==1 || row.entity.type==2 || row.entity.type==3 || row.entity.type==4? (\'notification.tooltipChange\' | translate)  : \'\'}}"'
      +'tooltip-placement="right" '
      +'translate="{{\'notification.message.type\'+row.entity.type}}" translate-values="{{row.entity}}">'
      +'</a>'
      + '</div>',
     enableColumnMenu: false,
   }
   ]
  };
var gridApiDefer = $q.defer();
  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
   $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
   //call when scrolling have reach the limit percentage.
   // retrieves next notifications based on current page number 
   gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope,function(){
      $http.get('resources/notifications?page='+$scope.page+'&size=15&type='+$scope.notifType)
        .success(function(notifList) {
         if(notifList.length > 0){
          // add notifications to the grid
          $scope.gridOptions.data = getData(notifList, $scope.page);
          ++$scope.page;
         }
          gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
        })
        .error(function() {
          gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
        });
   });
   
   gridApiDefer.resolve();
  };
  
  if($location.path().indexOf("/home/return") > -1){
   var notifs = notifCriteriaService.getCriteria();
   $scope.notifType = notifs.notifTypesList;
   $scope.page = notifs.page;
   $scope.gridOptions.data = notifs.notifsDataList;
   gridApiDefer.promise.then(function(){
    $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollTo($scope.gridApi.grid, $scope, $scope.gridOptions.data[20], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]); 
   });
  }else{
   $scope.getNotifs();
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-6">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollTo(20,0)">Scroll To Row 20</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="scrollToFocus(50,0)">Focus Row 50</button>
  <div>
   <div style="margin-top: 25px; background-color:#fff;">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-infinite-scroll ui-grid-cellNav></div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>

</div>
```

When I use the "scroll to" button, it works (not the scrollToFocus button but it is not the major problem). By debugging my code, I see that when I call scrollTo method automatically (ie: not with the button), the grid rows array is empty whereas it is filled when I use the button. 
I think that my grid is not yet fully initialized in the first scenario.

I think it could work because the ui-grid tutorial says:

> Provides an example of requesting a scroll to a specific row or column programatically - useful for remembering the state of a page and scrolling back to that position when a user returns.(http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav)

Do you see what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: this is my first post on this amazing site and English is not my native language, feel free to correct me if I use incorrectly stackoverflow tools ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you solved/worked around this sometime 9 months ago, but anyhow...

You are calling `$scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollTo(....);`

In the example at the uiGrid tutorial they are using `$scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo(...)`

It seems to me that this is a copy&paste error because you are using `$scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus(....);` somewhere else in your code.

Good luck